# I am not being able to see a detailed output of a server error?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, error-handling, httpwebrequest

In asp.net, i can't see the detailed message of the server when an error is present. I mean, when you open a browser and navigate to say http://[errorpage].com and the page shows something like "internal server error - the server is busy" - surely you know that the server is busy...but with my application i get only error 503 - but i cant go as far as mozilla browser goes and cannot see the entire error message. I tried to catch and display the exception - but...no. also i tried to parse the source with regular exp. - but i guess net stops whenever error is present and cannot proceed to parsing - also...without trycatching: same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, don't enable this on live websites.  In your web.config, add/edit the following:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

This will start showing detailed info about the error.  But again, DO NOT do this on a live server, or at least not permanently, as it is a security hazard.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to implement error handling into your code, then save errors somewhere (database, file ...) Then you can look into your file and get a full error

e.g.

```
try {
   //your code here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //write to file ex.ToString() to see whole stack trace, or ex.Message to see just message like "index out of bounds"
}
```

and also if you want to get errors in browser then turn it on in your config file

look at this link for details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I might consider the weblient like...putting in action the IE resources in c#. Now...error handling oesn't work in my case. For instance: MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); - tells me nothing more than....503 - no reason or any differences when i try different exception throwing (server busy, mysql failure, etc.).

Comment: `MessageBox` is part of Windows Forms, and won't work in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little manic, but you've got to consider what error handling is going on up the stack if this is happening:

```
try{
   //Something
}
catch(Exception){
   //Handle it some how
   throw new Exception("Broken");
}
```

then this will loose all of the call stack before the new exception is thrown. If this is happening it can be fixed like this:

```
try{
   //Something
}
catch(Exception){
   //Handle it some how
   throw;
}
```

this continues to throw the original exception with stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx), then ASP.NET will log details of the error to the Windows Event Log or any other destination you specify.